# Is there a factor in ffmpeg code that cuts video time?

Tags: ffmpeg

Im using ffmpeg to change resolution of video file and after conversion to another location the video lasts 0 seconds, but originally it lasts 2mins
My ffmepg code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale=480:320 -t 5 output.mp4
```

Comment: Edited the tag; this doesn't really have anything to do with `bash`; you're just using the program `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the -t modifier? You want to cut the video up? Otherwise, this will convert the whole length to the new quality.
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v scale480:320 output.mp4`